# How to use Scrapy Request and get response at same place?

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

I am writing the scrapy crawler to scrape the data from the e-commerce website.
The website has the color variant and each variant has own price, sizes and stock for that sizes.
To get the price, sizes, and the stocks for variant need to visit the link of the variant(color).
And all data needes in one record.
I have tried using requests but it is slow and sometimes fails to load the page.

I have written the crawler using `requests.get()` and use the response in the `scrapy.selector.Selector()` and parsing data.

What my question is, is there any way to use scrapy.Request() to get the response where I use it not at the callback function. I need the response at the same place as below(something like below),

```
response = scrapy.Request(url=variantUrl)
sizes = response.xpath('sizesXpath').extract()
```

I know `scrapy.Request()` require parameter called `callback=self.callbackparsefunction`
that will be called when scrapy generates the response to handle that generated response. I do not want to use callback functions I want to handle the response in the current function.

Or is there any way to return the response from the callback function to function where `scrapy.Request()` is written as below(something like below),

```
def parse(self, response):
    variants = response.xpath('variantXpath').extract()
    for variant in variants:
        res = scrapy.Request(url=variant,callback=self.parse_color)
        # use of the res response

def parse_color(self, response):
    return response
```

Comment: can you explain why callback is not an  option?

Comment: the callback is no option in my case because I do not want each variant as the separate product, I want it as part of one record and it is only three field that requires to load variant pages there are more fields that collected from the first page, not from the variant page, and variant is not only one there will be more than two, so I cannot use metadata that can be passed with request

Comment: in for loop, if you pass meta in Request object, I think each Request would build it's parsed data on top of meta dict

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [scrapy-inline-requests](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests) package, I think it's exactly what you are looking for.